# print out the whole Chinese dictionary with output { unicode, Chinese character)

Tags: dictionary, unicode, chinese-locale

Would some one show me how to print out the whole Chinese dictionary with output { unicode, Chinese character) in Java ?

```
String index = String.valueOf(i) ;
String chineseChar = "\\" + "u4e0" + index ;
System.out.println (index + " => " + chineseChar );
```

Last statement printed out
0 => \u4e00
The problem was the right hand side should have been a chinese character "One".

What is exactly the range of Chinese encoding in unicode ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Integer addition

```
String index = String.valueOf(i) ;
int chineseChar = '\u4e00' + i;
System.out.println (index + " => " + (char)chineseChar );
```

Comment: Thank you BlueMandora for your quick answer and it worked very well for me.